# While reading CSV, i'd like to set certain rows as different record types

Tags: neo4j

Here is the sudo node data I'm working with (the actual version has 4000 rows):

```
title temp
a.    1
b.    
c.    4
d.
```

Here is how I'm currently reading this data in:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes.csv" AS nodes
FIELDTERMINATOR ','
CREATE (n:record { name: nodes.title, id: nodes.temp })
```

Now, each of these nodes are not the same. Any node that has a blank value within the `temp` column, should be of type `n:franchise:record`.

If I wanted to do this once, I know how to using the following code:

```
match (n) where n.name = "a" set n:franchise:record
```

But this will become tedious to do for each of the records that have a blank value in `temp`.

I'm assuming there must be a way to do this while reading the data but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH COLLECT(nodes) AS allnodes
WITH [x IN allnodes WHERE x.temp IS null] AS franchises, [x IN allnodes WHERE x.temp IS NOT null] AS records
UNWIND records AS record
CREATE (n:Record { name: record.title, id: record.temp })
WITH franchise
UNWIND franchises AS franchise
CREATE (n:Franchises:Record { name: record.title})
```

I am assuming when you say "temp is blank", you mean `nodes.temp IS null`. If your definition also includes other conditions, for example, an empty string, then you need to update the cypher above accordingly.